# Add multiple graphs in a single page from multiple sources in Google Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I created a report in google data studio, which is composed of different pages containing pivot tables connected from the same googlesheet, but each pivot has as source different tabs.

[image]

Then each page contains a pivot from a separate data source:

[image]

- I would like to create a single page containing 3 of those pivot tables (the maximum number of pivot in the same page is 3, apparently). Is there a way to do so?

Basially I need to know whether one can create multiple graphs in a single page that are generated from multiple data sources (namely, the same googlesheet, but different tabs).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, each graph can have its own data source.

Go to Resource->Manage added data sources, and you will be able to select another worksheet from your Google Sheet to add as a new source.

Then, change the data source of your graph to the one you wish to display.